# How to set layout width of a button from code behind in Android Xamarin in C#?

Tags: c#, android, layout, code-behind

I am working with an Android button in Xamarin Android C# project.

```
<Button          
android:id="@+id/btn1"          
android:layout_width="120dp"          
android:layout_height="120dp"          
android:background="@drawable/ButtonImages"          
android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"   />
```

Here I want to set this **Android: layout_width="120dp"** and **Android: layout_marginLeft="35dp"** from code behind.

I got the button control from code behind by

```
Button btn1 = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btn1);
```

But unable to set **width** and **marginLeft**

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haven't tested this is xamarin, but ideally, this should work, please try and update. Here, I have set the height and weight to 120dp, you can modify it according to your need. Also can set the margins to your need by replacing the text.

```
Button btn1 = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btn1);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams (120,120);
params.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
btn1.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: This is giving me an error : java.lang.illegalargumentexception  . I tried with this ((MarginLayoutParams)btn1.LayoutParameters).Width = 120; ((MarginLayoutParams)btn1.LayoutParameters).LeftMargin = 35; and it was working fine

Comment: Can you specify the error exactly? 
Also, the above code you said is working for you, right? That also does the same job as the one which  I have suggested. So, I think your issue is solved. Thanks for the notice.

Comment: Yes, The above mentioned code works for me. Thanks for the support.

Comment: If the answer helped, please click on the small tick button at the bottom of the vote.